# Downgrade my project from django 1.5 to 1.4

Tags: django, mod-python, django-1.5, downgrade

I have a project in django 1.5 and I have to deploy it with mod_python. Unfortunately, I have seen that the module has been removed since 1.5. I know that there are another way such as mod_wsgi, gunicorn.. but could i downgrade my project to the previous version easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply take [this file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.10/django/core/handlers/modpython.py); which is the handler for mod_python from 1.4 and use it in 1.5.

You need to add it to a path that is accessible to Python and then set the `PythonHandler` directive in your Apache configuration to the module name.

Answer (score 2):

It should not be a problem to downgrade from Django 1.5 to 1.4 if you are not using any new features from 1.5, like configurable User model, for example.

For complete list of new features, please see [the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/).